# Evaluate an proper integral:$\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx$$

put $\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)=y^{1/n}$

$$I=\frac{\ln10}{2n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty10^{-y^{1/n}}y^{1/n}dy$$

put $10^{-y^{1/n}}=e^{-t}\implies$

$$I=\frac1{(2\ln10)^n}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-t}t^ndt+\frac1{(2\ln10)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^ndt$$

$$I=\frac1{(2\ln10)^n}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-t}t^ndt+\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(2\ln10)}$$

I want to know how can I evaluate the first integral in the last step of my turn I used some substitutions so i get two integrals one of them converted to the formula of gamma function but the second could not be so because the domain of integration is different ?
$n$ is a natural number

Comment: You know how to use MathJax (as shown in previous posts) so please use it when reasonable. Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are not view-able to some. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: What's the limit:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$$From this, can you see what's the problem here?

Comment: The integral diverges to $-\infty$

Comment: I have edited the qusetion the power n was missed

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx =\int_0^\infty x\left(-2\log\left(x\right)\right)^n dx$$
Now set
$u =-2\log\left(x\right)$ i.e $ x= e^{-\frac{u}{2}}$ which implies $~~u\to \infty ~~~as~~~ x\to 0^+$ and  $u\to \infty ~~~as~~ x\to \infty$ and $dx  = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{u}{2}}du $. Then
$$ \begin{split}
 I &= -\frac{1}{2} \int^{-\infty}_\infty e^{-\frac{u}{2}}u^ne^{-\frac{u}{2}}du \\
 &=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u}u^n ~du \\
 &=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^\infty e^{-u}u^n ~du +\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-u}u^n ~du\\ &=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(n+1)+\frac{(-1)^n}{2} \int_{0}^\infty e^{u}u^n ~du
 \end{split} $$

But the last integral does not converge. Since  $u>0\implies >e^u>1\implies u^ne^u>u^n$ that is
$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{u}u^n ~du>\int_{0}^\infty u^n ~du =\infty $$

> Hence $$I=\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx $$ Does not exist.